# How to design one recyclerview with 3 different styled cardview in navigation activity?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

How to design this? I need one recyclerview with 3 different styled cardview in navigation activity.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried recycler view with card view but did not work

Comment: Share your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you haven't provided any code or what you have done so far. 
I will give you a gist on how to achieve this.

First you need to understand how RecyclerView works with ViewHolder pattern. 
Next, each CardView item is populated using a custom adapter which I believe you have already done that.

In the custom adapter you should do something in this method

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

this method is very important if you are doing different layouts for different positions.

Also refer to this answer for more information.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6142219

This should get you started. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere